# Represent array of objects in Properties file java

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

Below I have represented my array of object in a my JAVA properties file

```
arrNew = [{"arrA": [{"type": "abc","id": "xyz","url": [{"name": "A","value": "http://a.com"},{"name": "B","value": "http://b.com"}]}]}]
```

How should I access the above values in the code ? Also, is there a better way to represent the above structure

Comment: Create a custom class for your data

Comment: It looks like JSON might be a good solution for you to represent this data.

Comment: Your second question ("is there a better way") is off-topic here because it is what is better is opinion based.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Value` annotation.

Just declare field in one of your bean like this:

```
@Value("${arrNew}")
private String value;
```

Spring will read it for you (of course your property should be in proper property file, for example `application.properties`).

Comment: You have to parse Json.